# ASP.NET with MVC 4.5 Framework using Angular JS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.NET with MVC 4 framework used with Angular JS. I want to write a program for get the data from XML API provider and it will display data on page and also stored on Database. Please help me with any example code.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I want to used http://travellanda.com/ xml api for hotel and car listing data service provider.